# Playframework is active menu item / route

Tags: playframework

I would like to style the active menu item, to do this i need to compare the current url agains a route. I know that I can do this in javascript, but I was wondering how other people have solved this in play.

Any suggestions?

Pseudocode:

```
<a #{routeIsActive Application.index()} class="active"#{/if} href="@{Application.index()}">My Page</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, I couldn't find an easy way to do this. The simplest solution I could find was to write a fast tag (but this may be due to my lack of Groovy experience).

I got this working with this code.

In your View

```
<a class="#{activeRoute href:@Application.index(), activeClass:'active' /}" href="@{Application.index()}">My Page</a>
```

Then, create a new FastTag for activeRoute

```
public class MyFastTag extends FastTags {

   public static void _activeRoute(Map<?, ?> args, Closure body, PrintWriter out, GroovyTemplate.ExecutableTemplate template, int fromLine) {
      Router.ActionDefinition actionDef = (Router.ActionDefinition) args.get("href");
      String activeStyle = (String) args.get("activeClass");
      String inactiveStyle  = (String) args.get("inactiveClass");

      if (Http.Request.current().action.equals(actionDef.action) && activeStyle != null) {
         out.print(activeStyle);
      }
      else if (!Http.Request.current().action.equals(actionDef.action) && inactiveStyle != null) {
         out.print(inactiveStyle);
      }
   }
}
```

Make sure you add the relevant imports.

This allows you to specify an active and inactive class, which is a little more than you requested

Comment: Why you use `else if` instead of an simple `else`?

Comment: because, if inactiveStyle is null, it would print null as the style, and I don't want anything printed if activeStyle or inactiveStyle are null.......The first part of the if is the same, but the second evaluation is different for the two if statements

Answer (score 11):

```
<a #{if request.action=="Application.index"}class="active"#{/if} href="@{Application.index()}">My Page</a>
```

Easy. :D

Comment: you can also check on controller base (useful for global navigation) like this: #{if request.controller=="ControllerClassName"}class="active"#{/if}

Answer (score 3):

This solution worked pretty well for me. It has the benefit to be very simple.

app/views/tags/navigationitem.js

```
%{
 boolean isMatch = request.path.startsWith(_href.toString());
}%
<li class="sliding-element">
#{if isMatch}
<h3>${_title}</h3>
#{/if}
#{else}
<a href="${_href}">${_title}</a>
#{/else}
</li>
```

app/views/tags/navigationmenu.js

```
#{js 'navigationmenu.js'/}
#{css 'navigationmenu.css'/}

<div id="navigation-block">
    <ul id="sliding-navigation">
        #{navigationitem title:'Home', href:@HomeController.index() /}
        #{navigationitem title:'Search Contact', href:@SearchByContactController.index() /}
        #{navigationitem title:'Edit Contact', href:@EditContactInfoController.index() /}
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This code work for me guys

```
<li @if(request.path.startsWith("/artigo")){ class="active" }>
    <a href="@routes.ArtigoController.telaLista"> Artigos</a>
</li>
```